# Disable some dates in datepicker by using AngularJs 1.0

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

How can i disable some of the dates in date-picker by using Angular js 1.0? 
I'm passing some dates through controller in an asp.net mvc web application. I want to disable those dates in the date-picker by using Angular js 1.0

Comment: Which one datepicker do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Make a Array of date strings which you wants to disabled and pass this from controller to view using `viewbag` or `ViewModel` or `Model` based on your coding architecture.

Pass this string array in `.datepicker` js function

```
$(".datepicker").datetimepicker({       
    datesDisabled: @viewBag.DisabledDates, // format should be like this ['2017/04/19','2017/04/18'] 
});
```

Change your datepicker as per your angular code